# TextPad printing to incorrect printer

Tags: printing, network-printer, textpad

I have tried to find an answer on Google, and searched SU, but have not found anything on this particular issue. I Looked for a setting in the TextPad menu and didn't see anything that seemed relevant. I have 2 networked printers that are the same model. (HP LaserJet 2200 Series PCL 5) One is near me and the other is across the building. The one near me is my default. It seems that TextPad remembers the last printer used and defaults to it rather than printing to the system default, so when I force it to print to my default printer once, the problem is solved until I decide to print to the other printer for some reason. If I don't remember the problem, and specifically print a job to the nearby printer to correct it, I'll end up either wasting paper or wasting trips across the building to pick up printjobs that got printed there by accident.

Has anyone else noticed this problem? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Looks that is a 'feature' of TextPad. They use a custom dialog to select the printer and remember the last one chosen. You could send a feature request to the developers.

I've switched from TextPad to [NotePad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for daily usage. You might check them out. Looks like they use the standard Windows print selection dialog.

Comment: I've used NotePadd++ a little. I don't rememeber why I went back to TextPad. Maybe I'll give it another try. If I don't get a better response, I'll come back and accept your answer. Thanks.